# Set custom Field of View using Google VR SDK

Tags: google-cardboard, google-vr

I'm trying to customize the SimpleVideoWidget sample of the Google VR SDK for Android (https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/sdk-simplevideowidget) so it will allow to use custom FoV (field of view).

Thank you in advance!